# Jmeter: Random number of labels everyday

Tags: jmeter, report, analytics

I am executing same test plan for two consecutive days:
First day no of `Label` (column A) are more than 1400
Second day no of `Label` are only 968 only

**First day:**
[image]

**Second day:**
[image]

I see that first day has samples 12, throughput almost zero and KB/sec 0.1
Second has better performance. Please help me understand:

1. What is difference between Label/Samples/Requests?
2. Do Number of labels depends on Throughput and Kb/sec i.e. Column K and L?

Answer (score 0):

1. Label is basically the name of the thread group in your case. it is basically the request name that you are hitting from JMeter.
2. Samples are the number of times that particular request was executed.

e.g. If you have some request called login and number of samples for login are 5 it means that the login request was executed 5 times during the test. 
The number of samples would vary based on the Test settings like number of users, iterations or duration of the test specified.

The number of labels = number of samples and throughput is related to each other.

```
Throughput = Number of Requests per second or minute and
Kb/Second = (Throughput* Average Bytes) / 1024
```

So the two are correlated.
I hope this helps.